# Testing Formik form with enzyme and jest

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, formik

I have form component(this is simplified example. In reality I have much more fields):

```
    <form className="film-form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <LabeledInput
          id="film-title"
          name="title"
          title="Title"
          value={formik.values.title}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          error={getErrorMessageForField('title')}
        />
          <Button
            title="save"
            onClick={formik.handleSubmit}
            className="film-form__actions__submit"
          />
    </form>
```

I use `useFormik` hook

```
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialState,
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      title: Yup.string().required('Title is required field'),
    }),
    onSubmit: onSave,
  });
```

and my validation and form works perfectly.
But when I decided to write test I found that enzyme always fails with the same error and I have no idea how to test such components/forms with enzyme

```
describe('FilmForm', () => {
  test('when all fields are empty then errors is displayed', async () => {
    const onSubmit = jest.fn();
    const onClose = jest.fn();
    const form = mount(
      <FilmForm
        title="Add film"
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        onClose={onClose}
        defaultGenres={[{ label: 'All', value: 'all' }]}
      />,
    );

    form.find('form.film-form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => {} });
    form.update();

    expect(form.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

As a result I see such error in output

```
console.error
    Warning: An update to FilmForm inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
```

And second one

```
 console.warn
    Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
        at getActiveElement (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6651:16)
        at getActiveElementDeep (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6939:17)
        at getSelectionInformation (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6972:21)
        at prepareForCommit (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:7463:26)
        at commitRootImpl (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22474:5)
        at unstable_runWithPriority (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:12)
        at runWithPriority$1 (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11039:10)
        at commitRoot (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22381:3)
        at finishSyncRender (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21807:3)
        at performSyncWorkOnRoot (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21793:7)
        at /home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11089:24
        at unstable_runWithPriority (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:12)
        at runWithPriority$1 (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11039:10)
        at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11084:7)
        at flushSyncCallbackQueue (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11072:3)
        at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21199:9)
        at dispatch (/home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15660:5)
        at /home/alesha/Documents/Projects/react-js-training/react-js-training/node_modules/formik/src/Formik.tsx:357:11
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

      at node_modules/formik/src/Formik.tsx:836:17
```

can anyone please help or share may be some articles
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Formik** itself has many asynchronous method and hook inside it, therefore in your test you also need to write in an asynchronous way.
Speaking of **testing hook** in general, i recommend you use `react-testing-library` together with `enzyme` and `jest`. You can have a glance here: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro

For more detail on how to use it specifically with `Formik`. I recommend you read [this article](https://hackernoon.com/react-forms-with-formik-and-unit-testing-with-react-testing-library-j0b32c9), quite a good explanation. ( Or can **google** '`test formik with react-testing library`')

Briefly, you need to cover it in a `wait` method of the library. Something like this:

```
  await wait(() => {
    fireEvent.change(color, {
      target: {
        value: "green"
      }
    })
  })

  await wait(() => {
    fireEvent.click(submit)
  })
```

Comment: You actually save my days